# deviceready not fired after 5 seconds Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, ios, sqlite, cordova

I get this console message

> deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
>
> Channel not fired: onPluginsReady
>
> Channel not fired: onCordovaReady

when I use the following ionic code snippet.

```
ionic.Platform.ready(function(){
    // will execute when device is ready, or immediately if the device is already ready.
    // some code here. I am making calls to sqlite cordova plugin
});
```

The control never goes inside the **ionic.Platform.ready** function. Funny thing is that my code works on android devices but don't work on iOS devices.

I have tried doing a lot of stuff so far. I have tried following the troubleshooting given in this link.
http://ngcordova.com/docs/common-issues/

The following is my configuration

> Cordova version 5.3.1
>
> Ionic version 1.6.4

Answer (score 1):

**window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard** was causing some issues as it is deprecated as of **Cordova version 3.0**. Now you need to use **window.cordova.require()** syntax to access the plugins.

Also removing and adding the ios platform helped.The package.json gets messed up sometimes.

Comment: Do you have any source for that?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this if not already included..

```
http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
```

To meta tag in your index.html file. It should look like..

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy".......>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue on iOS .Spent almost 3 to 4 days .Finally any of these two workarounds worked for me

1.add < meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy".......> to index.html

2.downgrade platform to 4.0.0 (cordova platform update iOS@4.0.0

Answer (score 0):

@grane2212,
You did not post any code, so it is difficult to debug this. Please post your index.html file, if this does not answer your question.

You may be loading your javascript support file from a CDN or the web. DO NOT DO THIS.
 *Load all *.js files locally.*

Let me know, if this helps.

Comment: I have all the .js files locally in my index.js. I won't be able to show much of my code. I only wanted to figure out  under what circumstances could I be getting this kind of errors.

Comment: Okay. I do NOT use ionic. I assumed this might be a general issue. At this point, I am recommending you post to http://forum.ionicframework.com/ There are likely people with much more knowledge on this subject that I. I would also recommend looking for an FAQ on ionic. To me this seems like a trivial issue. Best of Luck